# Get users by meeting id of a pivot table with laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have searched for related information but after trying I have not been able to get the results.

I have two many-to-many related tables, I need to list the users that are signed up for the same meeting (meeting_id).

This is the user model:

```
    public function meetings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Meeting::class);
    }
```

And this is the meeting model:

```
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

I have a pivot table: meeting_user, for example:

| ID | meeting_id | user_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |

I need to get a list: user_id 1, 2 and 4, because they are on meeting_id=1.

I have tried different ways but I can't get the list of users.

This is my controller:

```
    public function getUsersByMeeting(User $user, Meeting $meeting)
    {
        // $users = Meeting::find($meeting->id)->users->get();

        $users = $user->meetings()->where('meeting_id', $meeting->id)->get();

        return response()->json($users, 200);
    }
```

I don't know if the method needs the "User $user" parameter (Meeting $meeting yes, to get the $meeting->id).

Thanks !!

Comment: If you configured your relationships accordingly to the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many you should be able to do `$meeting->users`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have `Meeting $meeting` available in your method. From that variable, you can either access the  relationship directly with `->users` or a query builder with `->users()` if you need additional filtering.

If you don't need any additional filtering, you could just do

```php
public function getUsersByMeeting(User $user, Meeting $meeting)
{
    return response()->json($meeting->users, 200);
}
```

Note that this will include information about the pivot table.

Here are some of the options you can choose from.

```php
$users = $meeting->users;
$users = $meeting->users()->get();
$users = User::whereHas('meetings', fn ($q) => $q->where('meetings.id', $meeting->id))->get();
```